# vb.NET: Textbox TextChange

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Good day:)

I have a program with textboxes for Reference Number, Payee, Office and Address... What I want is that if the Reference Number exists in Obligation Table it will automatically put Payee, Office and Address, If not, you will type Payee's name but if exists in Payees table automatically it will put the Office and Address...

my problem is that it displays the correct result BUT a message box saying "No current query in data reader." I think the code are overlapping each other but i don't know how to resolve this.

Here's my code for txtRefNo.Text:

```
Private Sub txtRefNo_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRefNo.TextChanged
    Try
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ref_no, payee from bims_obligations " & _
                                                 "WHERE ref_no = '" & txtRefNo.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                txtPayee.Text = Reader("payee").ToString()
                txtOffice.Text = Reader("office").ToString()
                txtAddress.Text = Reader("address").ToString()

                txtPayee.Enabled = False
                txtOffice.Enabled = False
                txtAddress.Enabled = False

                certALoadGrid()

            End While

        Else

            txtPayee.Clear()
            txtOffice.Clear()
            txtAddress.Clear()

            txtPayee.Enabled = True
            txtOffice.Enabled = True
            txtAddress.Enabled = True

        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

and for txtPayee.text:

```
   Private Sub txtPayee_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPayee.TextChanged
    Try

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT * from bims_payee " & _
                                                 "WHERE payee = '" & txtPayee.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                txtOffice.Text = Reader("office").ToString()
                txtAddress.Text = Reader("address").ToString()

            End While

        Else

            txtOffice.Clear()
            txtAddress.Clear()

        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Looking forward for answers... or is there an if statement that if refNo exists then it will disregard textChange of txtPayee??? God bless :)

Comment: That is *not* good error handling. You're catching *any* exception, displaying *just* the message, then throwing away the stack trace and any inner exceptions. It's usually far better to only handle *specific* exceptions that you have a local strategy for dealing with, and letting any other exceptions pass up to a global exception handler which will log *all* of the details, then kill your process.

Comment: sorry, i'm not good in programming... and i really don't understand what you're saying... :( help! :)

Comment: I disagree with Damien_The_Unbeliever. The user would lose all the data they typed in if you handle the error in the manner he suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this line:

```
txtPayee.Text = Reader("payee").ToString()
```

Will cause `txtPayee_TextChanged` to fire. Which then calls:

```
modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()
```

You haven't shown us the code for those functions, but the names are certainly suggestive. You then use this global connection object inside `txtPayee_TextChanged`, and close it again at the bottom.

Finally, the code inside `txtRefNo_TextChanged` resumes with these lines:

```
txtOffice.Text = Reader("office").ToString()
txtAddress.Text = Reader("address").ToString()
```

But that `Reader` is associated with a connection that's been closed twice (or replaced, in some fashion, again, you've not shown that code) - and you'll have an error.

---

This is but *one* reason why having a globally shared `Connection` object is a bad idea (it's also bad if/when you want to start using background workers, Tasks, or anything else that involves multithreading).

It would be far better to just have a connection *string* in your `modGlobalFunctions` module. Then, inside each function, create separate `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects - placing each within `Using` statements. That way they will not interfere with each other.

I'm guessing that the

```
modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
```

Were added at the top of each function to cure an earlier symptom of the same issue

---

Also, as indicated in my comment - don't catch `Ex as Exception` and just display `Ex.Message`. You have no idea what exceptions *might* be thrown, and you're disposing of a lot of useful information (such as the Stack Trace and Inner Exception)

---

E.g. this is how I'd write your first sub:

```
Private Sub txtRefNo_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRefNo.TextChanged
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString) 'Our own private connection, no one else can interfere
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ref_no, payee from bims_obligations WHERE ref_no = @RefNo", conn) 'Using parameters, safer SQL
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefNo", txtRefNo.Text)
            conn.Open() 'Open the connection
            Dim Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If Reader.HasRows Then
                While Reader.Read
                    txtPayee.Text = Reader("payee").ToString()
                    txtOffice.Text = Reader("office").ToString()
                    txtAddress.Text = Reader("address").ToString()

                    txtPayee.Enabled = False
                    txtOffice.Enabled = False
                    txtAddress.Enabled = False

                    certALoadGrid()

                End While

            Else

                txtPayee.Clear()
                txtOffice.Clear()
                txtAddress.Clear()

                txtPayee.Enabled = True
                txtOffice.Enabled = True
                txtAddress.Enabled = True

            End If
            Reader.Close() 'Not really necessary, but anyway
        End Using
    End Using 'These have cleaned up our connection and command objects
        'If an exception has occurred, we don't know what it is, or how to recover
        'So we don't try and catch it.
End Sub
```